# React Material UI Dropdown Menu Icon

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, icons

I'm trying to create a custom dropdown menu using the Material UI (MUI) Autocomplete API ([found here](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/) and [here](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/)). Right now, I'm trying to change the arrow icon at the end of the textbox to the ExpandMore icon also from MUI (found [here](https://material-ui.com/components/material-icons/)). However, my code is not working. I would really appreciate any help I can get on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Autocomplete API there is popupIcon prop, which is used to change icon at the end. Here is customized doc example:

```
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';

import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      popupIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon/>}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />}
    />
  );
}
```